# How to bind a function to every other function call?

Tags: javascript, function-calls

Today I painstakingly merged several thousand lines of code from three different files into a single .js file. The files all had the same origin but evolved in different projects with some slight (but crucial) differences.

I managed to merge the thingies and kept all the best stuff from the duplicate functions.
So far so good...

But now I'm still stuck with around 1700 lines of JavaScript of which a lot might still be redundant or completely obsolete.

To solve this problem I came up with the following idea: can I bind a function to the Function.prototype so I can keep track of the usefulness of the functions in the project?

So far I've come up with this, but it requires me to add code to every function, which is no good.

```
Function.prototype.useful= function () {
    // This should be called by every function.
    console.log(this.name);
};

function someFunction() {
    arguments.callee.useful(); // No good.
    // Irrelevant.
}

someFunction();
```

Can I make this so every (non-native) function calls `useful()` automatically?

Comment: Can't you just profile your code and see which functions get 0 runtime?

Comment: No, I might have to log them in localStorage over a longer duration. It's not something I want to test myself.

Comment: It depends on where the `someFunction`s are defined. Yes, you will need to explicitly add the profiler to each function, but if there's an enumerable collection of functions you might be able to do less writing.